# MySQL ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

The software im using automatically creates 2 mysql users during installation. Because of a slight issue those users were created wrongly and the Support advised me to remove the users form the database and then recreate them using the installer (theres a separate option to just create the database users).

The two users are `'username'@'localhost'` and `'username'@'%'` (yes, they have the same username on different hosts..)

My problem is that neither `DROP USER 'username'@'localhost';` nor `DROP USER 'username'@'%'`; work, both throw an ERROR 1396.

My guess would be that it has to do with the user accounts "owning" elements in the database which would be orphaned. Is there a way to get past this and remove the users anyways? (Since they are gonna be recreated in a second?)

Clarification: Im using the mysql root user.

Comment: What is your **current** account? It must differ from both accounts to be deleted, and it must have according permission.

Comment: You could try  deleting from `mysql` database. `use mysql;` then  `delete from user where user='username' and host ='localhost'; `

Answer (score 0):

[Ergest Basha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16461952/ergest-basha)'s suggestion in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70784685/mysql-error-1396-hy000-operation-drop-user-failed-for-usernamelocalhost/70786266#comment125137037_70784685) worked for me:

> You could try deleting from mysql database. `use mysql;` then `delete from user where user='username' and host ='localhost';`